# JSlint warning "Move variable declaration to top of function or script."

Tags: javascript, jslint

I don't know why there is a warning of "Move variable declaration to top of function or script."
Although I move the variable "myName" to other places, the variable below will be the new one having the same warning. I have input "window, document" in the "Options" section in JSlint.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  "use strict";
  var myLogin = document.forms.submitForm;
  myLogin.onsubmit = processForm;
  var myName = document.getElementById("result__username");
  var myPassword = document.getElementById("result__password");
  var myMessage = document.getElementById("output");
  myMessage.classList.add("displaynone");

  function processForm() {
    var in_username = myLogin.username;
    var in_password = myLogin.password;


    if (in_username.value === "") {
      in_username.classList.add("changered");
      in_username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    in_username.classList.add("changewhite");
    if (in_password.value === "") {
      in_password.classList.add("changered");
      in_password.focus();
      return false;
    }
    in_password.classList.add("changewhite");
    myName.innerHTML = in_username.value;
    myPassword.innerHTML = in_password.value;
    myMessage.classList.add("displayblock");
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Probably complaining you have `myLogin.onsubmit = processForm;` before the other vars.

Comment: I have put it after the variables below, but there will be much more errors.

Comment: You move it to the line where `myMessage.classList.add("displaynone");` is....

Comment: Yes, but there will be 28 more errors after doing so,
Expected 'var' at column 5, not column 1.
Expected 'myMessage' at column 5, not column 1.
Expected 'myLogin' at column 5, not column 1.
Expected 'function' at column 5, not column 1.
Expected 'var' at column 9, not column 1.
and many...

Comment: That means your indenting is all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a linter, you need to follow what ever rules you have applied. You need to move the vars before you touch the variables. You need to indent right. Set up your IDE with plug ins that will format your code for you.

```
window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";

    var myLogin = document.forms.submitForm;
    var myName = document.getElementById("result__username");
    var myPassword = document.getElementById("result__password");
    var myMessage = document.getElementById("output");

    myMessage.classList.add("displaynone");
    myLogin.onsubmit = processForm;

    function processForm() {
        var in_username = myLogin.username;
        var in_password = myLogin.password;


        if (in_username.value === "") {
            in_username.classList.add("changered");
            in_username.focus();
            return false;
        }

        in_username.classList.add("changewhite");

        if (in_password.value === "") {
            in_password.classList.add("changered");
            in_password.focus();
            return false;
        }

        in_password.classList.add("changewhite");

        myName.innerHTML = in_username.value;
        myPassword.innerHTML = in_password.value;

        myMessage.classList.add("displayblock");
        return false;
    }
};
```